# How to replace subquery with joins (or similar)

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I'm currently working through some exam for university and I'm kinda stuck with the current task

*I know I'm supposed to solve that alone but im stuck and desperate*

> Who lent the same book as Ms. Schmitz did? Print out their last names

You are **not allowed to use subqueries** though

---

Here is my try:

```
SELECT l.Nachname
FROM Ausleihe as a
LEFT JOIN Leser as l on a.LeserOID = l.LeserOID
WHERE ExID IN (
  SELECT ExID
  FROM Ausleihe
         LEFT JOIN Leser L2 on Ausleihe.LeserOID = L2.LeserOID
  WHERE l2.Nachname = 'Schmitz'
);
```

this works perfect but its with subqueries.

---

Here is the database structure.
[image: Structure]

```
**Buch -> Book**
BuchOID -> BookOID
Titel -> Title
Verfasser -> Author

**Vormerkung -> Reservartion**
LeserOID -> ReaderOID
BuchOID -> BookOID
VormDat -> Reservation date

**Leser -> Reader**
LeserOID -> ReaderOID
Nachname -> Last name
Mail

**Exemplar -> Copy**
BuchOID -> BookOID
ExID -> CopyID
AnschDat -> Date of aqusition

**Ausleihe -> Lending**
BuchOID -> BookOID
ExID -> CopyID
LeserOID -> ReaderOID
LNr -> *PK of this table*
ADat -> Lending date
RDat -> Return date

**Mahnung -> Reminder**
MahnungOID -> ReminderOID
LeserOID - > ReaderOID
BuchOID -> BookOID
ExID -> CopyID
Datum -> date
Betrag -> amount
```

Comment: Please explain how your data model represents that someone lent a book.  It is not obvious (at least to an English-speaker).

Comment: @GordonLinoff did some explanation. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
SELECT l.Nachname
FROM Ausleihe as a
LEFT JOIN Leser as l on a.LeserOID = l.LeserOID
JOIN Leser L2 on a.LeserOID = L2.LeserOID
   WHERE l2.Nachname = 'Schmitz'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it does not solve the problem though. 
I am supposed to get the last name of all the people that lent the same book *exemplare* from the library as Ms. Schmitz did

Answer (score 1):

if you are using left join it will return resuls with null if no relation, so you need to add condition if not null

```
SELECT l.Nachname
FROM Ausleihe as a
LEFT JOIN Leser as l on a.LeserOID = l.LeserOID
LEFT JOIN Leser L2 on Ausleihe.LeserOID = L2.LeserOID
WHERE L2.Nachname is not null and L2.Nachname = 'Schmitz'
```

OR with inner join you can do something like this

```
SELECT l.Nachname
FROM Ausleihe as a
LEFT JOIN Leser as l on a.LeserOID = l.LeserOID
INNER JOIN Leser L2 on (Ausleihe.LeserOID = L2.LeserOID AND and L2.Nachname = 'Schmitz')
```

or just like this

```
SELECT l.Nachname
FROM Ausleihe as a
LEFT JOIN Leser as l on a.LeserOID = l.LeserOID
INNER JOIN Leser L2 on Ausleihe.LeserOID = L2.LeserOID
WHERE L2.Nachname = 'Schmitz'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it does not solve the problem though. 
I am supposed to get the last name of all the people that lent the same book *exemplare* from the library as Ms. Schmitz did